# Feature Request: Profile vote breakout up/down by questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, voting

Currently, on my profile page, I can see the number of up and down votes I have cast.  This is good for getting a feel for how often I upvote vs. downvote, and also for the total number of votes I have cast.

I would like to see this total broken out by total, votes on questions, and votes on answers.

Specifically, I'm going for the Electorate badge, and I'd like to see how close I am.  This is why I'm asking for this specific feature.  I think it would be good for more reasons - really the more information we have the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Completed!**

This feature has been silently rolled out, it seems.  Thank you, SO!

Answer (score 5):

We need some mysteries in life.  The electorate badge can be one of them.

Besides, you better use your votes for good/bad posts, not for badges.

Comment: -1 Don't tell me what to use my votes for.